# Trouble with updating subdocuments on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

say i have a collection `allitems` where each document is of the form

```
{_id: "1", items: [{number: 1, main: "how are you?", sub:[{id:1, item: "does it change with the day?", score: 0},{id:2, item:"some other question", score: 0}]}]}
```

How do I update the score on a subitem?

I've tried

```
 db.allitems.update({_id:"1"}, {$set:{'items.0.sub.0.score': 5}});
```

I get this error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: items.0.sub.0.score",
    "code" : 13097
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `$set` instead of `set` and quote keys that use dot notation.

```js
db.allitems.update({_id:"1"}, {$set: {'items.0.sub.0.score': 5}})
```

Comment: this was a typo...this doesnt fix the problem and the error seems to be indicating something else.

Comment: Never mind....i had the dumbest error ever....i was using "find" instead of "update".....>=2 hours of my life may or may not have been wasted :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hahaha exact same thing happened to me, you don't notice the .find! Especially when you're commenting out stuff

Comment: I'm so ashamed haha, I was using Find() too :D

Comment: Same here :) First testing the query and the adding the update part to find :)

Comment: ha ha, I'm a new one, wasted for 2h until see your comment